# Laravel User Roles recursive

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, roles

I use Laravel with UserAuth and Roles. All works fine. Now I want to add many Roles.
The Roles Should be Recursive.

```
   Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

    });

   Schema::create('role_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id');
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('child_id');
        $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

`$user->roles();` give me all roles where the user is direct asigned.

Example:

User is in Role1 in role_user table

Role 1 is in Role 2 in role_role table

Role 2 is in Role 3 in role_role table

`$user->roles();` Result is Role1.

`$user->roles();` Result should contain Role1, Role2, Role3. Not as text. It should be an array

I've to manipulate

```
    public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

But how?

Very Thanks.

Comment: user_id in role_user not unique?

Comment: Every User can have More Roles. And A Role can be in other Roles.

Comment: Maybe Group is better than role. I can rename it, But it is the same problem.

Comment: please mention what you are trying what result you getting and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a recursive relationship:

```
    public function childrenRoles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function allChildrenRoles()
    {
        return $this->childrenRoles()->with('allChildrenRoles');
    }
```

You can then access all your roles using

```
    $role = Role::with('allChildrenRoles')->first();
    $role->allChildrenRoles->first()->allChildrenRoles; // .. and so on
```

Comment: I don't want to know child roles from an parent roll, but all roles from an user.
there must be a change in public function roles() in user model.

Comment: your roles are recursive, to access them - this is the best solution. There is no single query that can retrieve all roles in your situation

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own Solutions and it works good.

Role.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function belongsToUser(User $user,$int)
{
    if ($this->hasUser($user)) {
        return true;
    }
    $children = $this->childrenRoles();
    if ($int > 10) {
        return false;
    }
   foreach ($children->get() as $child)
    {
        if ($child->belongsToUser($user,$int+1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function childrenRoles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_role', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
}

public function hasUser(User $user)
{
    return null !== $this->users()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
}



}
```

User.php

```
public function roles()
{
    $r = Role::where('id','<>', 'null');
    foreach ($r->get() as $role)
    {
        if (! $role->belongsToUser($this,0)) {
            $r = $r->where('id', '<>', $role->id);
        }
    }
    return $r->get();
}
```